# Transpose one row to two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a data sheet with approx 90k Rows and I need to transpose data in every row to 2 columns. To explain a bit more, I am having product id in the 1st column and the next few ( each product id is having different sizes and stock) cells are having the sizes and stock, but I want to have all that data in two columns only instead of only one row. For reference, I have attached the screenshot.

1. The first screenshot is about the raw data [image: First Screenshot]
2. The second screenshot is how I want the data to be placed [image: second screenshot]

My code was

```vb
Sub TransposeInsertRows()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20161125
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox _
    (Prompt:="Range Selection...", _
    Title:="Product base", Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    x = xRg(1, 1).Column + 2
    y = xRg(1, xRg.Columns.Count).Column
    For i = xRg(xRg.Rows.Count, 1).Row To xRg(1, 1).Row Step -1
        If Cells(i, x) <> "" And Cells(i, x + 1) <> "" Then
            k = Cells(i, x - 2).End(xlToRight).Column
            If k > y Then k = y
            For j = k To x + 1 Step -1
                Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                With Cells(i + 1, x - 2)
                    .Value = .Offset(-1, 0)
                    .Offset(0, 1) = .Offset(-1, 1)
                    .Offset(0, 2) = Cells(i, j)
                End With
                Cells(i, j).ClearContents
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before running code
[image: Earlier]

After running code
[image: After]

Comment: Bigben kindly let me know, what points I have missed there?

Comment: I have added it, Kindly check, and about code, This code helped me in inserting blanks rows but, it only copy-pasted the first input in every row that was inserted, not the values from every column, let me attach the screenshot

Comment: I have added the screenshots of how code worked, Kindly check now.

Comment: Let me send you the code, code is, not allowing me to paste here

Comment: Would you like a complementar code able to process the sheet as it looks after your preliminare processing?

Comment: You label your first screenshot as raw data. Is that really the case?  How are the number of blank rows determined by your data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "real raw" data consists of sequential rows, with the data for each `id` in adjacent columns, then you can (relatively) easily solve your problem using Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)

I am assuming your original data looks something like:

[image]

That being the case, using Power Query you can:

- Select the id column and Unpivot other columns
- Group by each pair of rows
- Extract the values from the `size-stock` columns which gives you a comma separated pair of values
- Group by the `id` which creates a column of Tables for each id

  - Add a blank row to the bottom of each table (gives you the blank rows in your results
- Expand the tables, and create a column where only the first id entry for each set of stock-sizes is showing.
- Along the way extra columns are removed, and data types get set.

If you paste the M-Code below into the Power Query Advanced Editor, and change the Table Name in Line 2 to reflect your data table, you should be able to follow along in the `Applied Steps` window to see what is going on.

In that window, double clicking the steps with a little gearwheel on the right will open a dialog window which will show useful information.

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"id"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 2), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Attribute", "Index"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Integer-Division", "id"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [id=nullable number, Value=any, #"Integer-Division"=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Sizes Stock", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Sizes Stock", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Sizes Stock", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Sizes Stock.1", "Sizes Stock.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Integer-Division", "Grouped"}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"id"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [id=nullable number, Sizes Stock.1=nullable text, Sizes Stock.2=nullable number]}}),
    
    //Change List.Repeat count argument for number of blank rows between each id
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Custom", each Table.InsertRows([Grouped],Table.RowCount([Grouped]),
            List.Repeat({[id = "", Sizes Stock.1 = "", Sizes Stock.2=""]},1))),

    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"id", "Grouped"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Custom", {"id", "Sizes Stock.1", "Sizes Stock.2"}, {"id", "Sizes Stock.1", "Sizes Stock.2"}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "ID.1", each if [Index]= 0 then [id] else 
   if #"Added Index1"[id]{[Index]-1} = [id] 
      or [id] = "" then null 
   else [id]),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"id"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns3",{{"ID.1", "id"}, {"Sizes Stock.1", "Size"}, {"Sizes Stock.2", "Stock"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"id", "Size", "Stock", "Index"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"id", type text}, {"Size", type text}, {"Stock", type number}}),
    #"Removed Columns4" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type3",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns4"
```

**Results**

[image]

***Note:** if you want more than one blank row between each set of `id` values, a minor change in the code will do that.

Comment: Ron thanks for the query, but I am getting errors at a lot of points in this query

Answer (score 2):

You did not answer my clarification question...

Then, test the next code, please. It assumes that you have the sheet to be processed, prepared as you show it in the picture (processed with enough spaces between the rows with data:

```
Sub TESTSplitTransposeArrays()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant
 Dim lastCol As Variant, lastcolUR As Long, k As Long, j As Long, lastRlastCol As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your worksheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastcolUR = sh.UsedRange.Columns.count
 arr = sh.Range(sh.Range("A1"), sh.cells(lastRow, lastcolUR)).Value
 lastRlastCol = sh.cells(lastRow, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 ReDim arrFin(1 To lastRow + Int((lastRlastCol - 1) / 2) + 2, 1 To 2)
 
 For i = 2 To lastRow
    If sh.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        lastCol = sh.cells(i, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arr = sh.Range(sh.Range("B" & i), sh.cells(i, lastCol)).Value
        For j = 1 To lastCol - 1
            If j Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                arrFin(i + k - 1, 1) = arr(1, j)
                arrFin(i + k - 1, 2) = arr(1, j + 1)
                k = k + 1
            End If
          Next j
          k = 0
    End If
 Next i

 sh.Range(sh.Range("B2"), sh.cells(lastRow, lastcolUR)).ClearContents
 sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

But, if the necessary blank rows have not been inserted, use the next code, please:

```
Sub testInsertMassRows()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, roNo As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  
  For i = lastR To 2 Step -1
    roNo = sh.cells(i - 1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    sh.Rows(i & ":" & i + Int(roNo / 2) + 2).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
  Next i
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Edited:

If your workbook will not be consistent, meaning not having the necessary pairs to be extracted, the code will return an error (a half row cannot be inserted and an array cannot be Redim using decimals). In order to check this aspect, please, previously run the next checking `Sub`. It will send a message with all the problematic rows address. Correct them and run the other subs only after this check. If everything will run smooth from your point of view and you need often running such an application, I can transform this last `Sub` in a function to be called by the other two, to preliminary check and go on only if it will return `True`:

```
Sub testInconsistencyCheck()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, ColNo As Long, strInc As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To lastR
    ColNo = sh.cells(i - 1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    If ColNo Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        strInc = strInc & sh.Rows(i).Address & vbCrLf
    End If
  Next i
  If Not strInc = "" Then
    MsgBox "Wrong number of columns on row(s):" & vbCrLf & strInc
  Else
    MsgBox "Everything OK!"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error, " Runtime error -13Type mismatch" Degubber shows error in line sh.Rows(i & ":" & i + roNo / 2 + 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

Comment: @anuj kundu: This only means inconsistency in your data. It means that on the specific `i` row, the last column is not an odd number as it should be. You can check that, moving the cursor over the `roNo` variable and see if it is odd. In this case its division will not be an integer and Excel cannot insert half of a row... :) But I will adapt the code to also handle such cases. I mean, it will use an integer resulted from the division and add an extra row...  **Adapted the code**. Please, test it now. Do not forget to refresh the page (this one)...

Comment: @anuj kundu: But you must check the workbook consistency. If your data are wrong, neither the array used to split the values will also return errors. You should check which row has the problem and correct it. I can try adapting the main code, in order to avoid errors, but only by skipping the last record... Or, maybe better, I will make a piece of code to preliminary check the worksheet from this point of view. And finally send a list of problematic rows. I do not have time to do it right now, but I can do it if the problematic rows are a lot. This is something you must appreciate, I think. :)

Comment: Is it possible for us to have a skype call, where I can share my screen with you?

Comment: Thanks a ton mate, I appreciate your knowledge and efforts. Its done

Comment: @anuj kundu: Is it "done" by my code, or using another one?

Comment: @fanedaru I really appreciate your efforts, but am sorry to say but, solution provided by Ron worked in a single shot.

Comment: @anuj kundu: No problem with me! It is normal to choose the solution which best fits your needs. I only wanted to know if it would be good to make the last `Sub` a function... Understood now that it is not the case, anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you do not clear anything from your sheet named "Sheet1".
You will have problems as your transposed rows may erase the datas in "Sheet1".
Try building all your datas in arrays and then write all the values in a new sheet.

Comment: Sylvain in truth, I have at least got the blank rows as per the data I need to transpose, Arrays won't work